# Forward vertical scrolls from UIScrollView to a sibling UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uikit

I have a view controller with this hierarchy:

View Controller:

- UIScrollView (scrollable horizontally)
- UITableView (scrollable vertically)

[image]

I want to forward the vertical scrolls from my `UIScrollView` to the sibling `UITableView`, so that when the user scrolls up on the `UIScrollView`, the `UITableView` will scroll up instead. What would be the best way to do it?

I have tried these:

- Detecting the vertical scroll in `scrollViewDidScroll`, it doesn't get called because the contentOffset of the scroll view does not change.
- Subclassing the `UIScrollView` and overriding `touchesMoved`, I can't forward the touches to the table view because I don't have a reference to it in this class.

Comment: You can do this by creating a transparent view on top of your scrollView and using it to capture gestures. Pass through vertical gestures; intercept horizontal gestures and pass them to the tableView. The key piece is overriding the hitTest:withEvent method in your transparent view. (If that's not enough to go on, lemme know and I'll post an actual answer. :-)

Answer (score 3):

If the tableview is contained within the scroll view I believe you can set up the scroll view's gesture recognizers to respond only if the table view's gesture recognizers fail.  I haven't had a chance to try this, but you should be able to set up a dependency between the gestures for each of the views.

```
UITableView* tableView = ...;
UIScrollView* scrollView = ...;
for (UIGestureRecognizer* r in scrollView.gestureRecognizers)
{
    for (UIGestureRecognizer* tableRecognizer in tableView.gestureRecognizers)
    {
        [r requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tableRecognizer];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This will make your scroll simultaneously with `UITableView` and `UIScrollView` and apply **@Stephen Johnson**'s block

```
 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
 shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
 {
     return YES;
 }
```

Comment: can you elaborate some more? I can not get this to work. Thanks!

Comment: would you explain more? I can't set `self` as `UIScrollViewGestureRecognizer` delegate!